# Angular2.3 Custom Library and dependency injection

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ionic2

I am trying to inject a service from a custom library created with yeoman  into my existing ionic2 project. The index.ts  of the lib (which will be installed as npm module)  :

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        SampleComponent,
        SampleDirective,
    ],
    exports: [
        SampleComponent,
        SampleDirective,
        SamplePipe
    ]
})
export default class SampleModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SampleModule,
            providers: [SampleService, SettingsSVC]
         };
    }
}
```

In my ionic2 App I want to  inject SettingsSVC and the module.ts. If I add it to the imports-Section of the app.module it says :

Unexpected value 'SettingsSVC' imported by the module 'AppModule'

If not, I get a console error "provider not found".

The type (class regardless of the `@Injectable`) itself is recognized and linked and If I add the same class to my Ionic2 App and its providers section in the module it is working with Injection.

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SampleModule.forRoot()],
  declaretions: [],
  providers: []
})
export class YourAppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

When it says unexpected value , normally means what ever you're importing is not successfully imported.

Either :

1- Path of the SettingsSVC is wrong

2- The name of SettingsSVC is wrong

3- The path is correct but SettingsSVC is not exported

So to make sure your import is actually imported SettingsSVC , put a console.log after it and log it out

```
import {SettingsSVC} from 'the/path/'

console.log('SettingsSVC',SettingsSVC);
```

If the log says undefined , it's definitely one of the above ( or maybe something similar ).

And by the way , I got a bit confused , did you want to import SettingsSVC as a service and put it into your providers or did you want to import it as a module and put it into imports:[] ?

You can't have both!